# What exactly is the purpose/function of autoraise in webbrowser library, Python?

Tags: python, python-webbrowser

I have tried to us webbrowser.open function to open a url with the following code:

`webbrowser.open('https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html', new = 2, autoraise = True)`

Basically, the code runs as expected, but when I change `autoraise = True` to `autoraise = False`, the code runs the same, there is no difference at all.

So, I checked the documentation and found the following answer: *If autoraise is True, the window is raised if possible. The term “raise” means to bring it to the front.* However, the functionality of it is still unclear to me, due to the fact that there was no noticable difference as mentioned above.

I would be grateful, if anyone could clarify the topic for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It basically means it will bring it to the front, the first window!

Comment: That I understand, but why does it still bring the page to the front even when autoraise is set to False? I am using Chrome as a browser, so should I assume that it is because of the browser?

Comment: Yep, That's because of the brower

Answer (score 1):

According to the full documentation:

> If autoraise is True, the window is raised if possible **(note that under many window managers this will occur regardless of the setting of this variable).**

As it seems, in most cases `autoraise`'s value doesn't really matter.